# Angular UI $modal and scope confusion when passing data to and from the modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am just getting into Angular and am finding the $modal dialog confusing.   I cannot get the modal's `close()` method to work, though I'm following the documentation:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close(["cat","dog"]);
  };
```

In the code snippet below, from [the online docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), **inside** the `ModalInstanceCtrl` function, does `$scope` refer to the scope of `ModalDemoCtrl` or the scope of `ModalInstanceCtrl`?   I am also confused by the appearance of the `items` parameter in the ModalInstanceControl signature, since `items` also appears in the `resolve` section of the $modal config.

```
<snip>

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });




var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Comment: The `$scope` variable is different for each controller. In `resolve` you define what objects you want to pass as additional parameters from your page controller to the modal controller. That is why you must put `items` back into the `$scope` of the modal controller if you display them in the modal template.

Comment: But if items are passed to the modal via `resolve`, why does the `ModalInstanceCtrl` function also have `($scope, $modalInstance, items)` signature?

Comment: The `ModalInstanceController` is a regular controller defined the same way as your page controller. It has its own `$scope` variable to use in its template. Inside your page controller, the `$modal` service will link the specified `templateUrl` with the `ModalInstanceController` and will send the same modal instance received from `$modal.open()`, plus the objects defined in `resolve`. It allows you to `dismiss` or `close` *that* modal instance from the modal controller and to wait for the `result` of *that same* modal instance back in the page controller.

Comment: OK, I think I'm understanding better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**We can achieve through Isolated Scope:** pass some values from the parent scope to the directives

There’re 3 types of prefixes AngularJS provides

1. "@"   (  Text binding / one-way binding )
2. "="   ( Direct model binding / two-way binding )
3. "&"   ( Behaviour binding / Method binding  )

All these prefixes receives data from the attributes of the directive element.

```
 class="directive"

 name="{{name}}"

 color="color"
```

When the directive encounters a prefix in the scope property, it will look for an attribute ( with same property name ) on directive’s html element

```
 scope : {    
  name: "@"    
 }
```

I've followed this link`http://jsfiddle.net/shidhincr/pJLT8/10/light/`